# how to scroll a part of html body as vertical

Tags: html, dojo

[image]

I am using this type of design in my html and now i want that blue part as a scroll_view vertically in dojo. If I do this for blue div , it is not working for me the whole part is scrolling vertically. I want all part constant with blue as scroll view. How to do that in dojo.

Comment: why -1 , tell if i asked wrong question.......this rediculas

Answer (score 1):

you can use dojo scrollable pane in side a view. check out the below link

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/layout/ScrollPane

if you still do not get it ping me back.